# JSQMessages with Parse - Installation issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, parse-platform, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm looking to implement  [JSQMessages](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) into my existing Xcode project.
I tried using CocoaPods but was unable to fix all the errors. I got so far as to only having an error with the Parse-lib not being found but after having no luck getting rid of it (had to do with the debug-iphoneos) I gave up and uninstalled all of the CocoaPods and returned to having my project with only Parse.

I read on the github page that you can install it manually just by putting the folder for JSQMessage and JSQSystemSoundPlayer into your folder project but I have not been able to figure that one out. So my question to you guys is if anyone knows the exact procedure of doing it manually, because simply putting them in your project folder and importing them both into my bridging file wasn't successful and Xcode gave me an error that it wasn't able to find the headerfiles.

Comment: When you drag these folders into your project in Xcode, are you selecting the `Create groups` option? (Instead of the `Folder reference` option.) I ran into problems with doing the latter in my own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend you to look on this library for implementing chat 
[SlackTextViewController](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController)

It could be installed via cocoapods or by dragging source of the library to your project.

On my experience working with JSQMessages, it's too buggy when you have a lot of messages in the chat

Comment: Ok thanks :) But I still don't understand how I should install this just by dragging the folder to my project. That part just seems far to simple and I don't get it, because doing just that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I tried installing that and using some other fixes I have no been able to get as far as being able to build my project after installing cocoapods. 
But when I add a ViewController with the class of SLKTextViewController (this does actually show in the list of available classes) I can't build it anymore. It tells me "Use of undeclared type 'SLKTextViewController'". How is it one part of Xcode can find it but another can't? I'm starting to think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong...